# Accessing an ID via a variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working on a JS project and I've hit a wall. I have assigned var ids with values from an JSON objects attribute. Down the line in my code there is another JSON call to an slightly different object, thats has the same values from my previous call but under a different attribute. I' not being able to call those IDs using the attributes names, I can't figure out what I'm missing. This is the piece of code of whe the ID is assigned

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="'+x._links.self+'">
```

and this is the piece of code of my call to the ID

```
$("'#"+y._links.channel+"'").html('<p>Offline</p>');
```

which is inside another JSON call

I'm not being able to access the variable uner the id, I have tried different ways such as getElementById() and haven't been able to change its contents.
would greatly aprecciate some insight. Cheers

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. Could you be more explicit, please?

Comment: Okay, I have a for loop inside of which I"m making a AJAX call to retrive a JSONP file, as the loop goes around I'm assigning IDs to new divs being created these IDs receive the value of an attribute of the JSONP (first snippent of code). Down the line theres another for loop and anothe AJAX call to a different JSONP but that has an attribute with the exact same value of the attributes I used to assign the IDs of the divs(second snippet), I have been able to access the values in the JSONP however once I set it as an ID I'm not being able to call those ID's (also second snippet)

Comment: $("'#"+y._links.channel+"'") should read $("#" + x._links.channel) Correct?

Comment: No, the the 'x' is the first AJAX the 'y' is the second, Ihave been trying differnt ways of formmating bothe the assignment of the ID as well as the call to it

Comment: It also look like <div class="col-md-6" id="'+x._links.self+'"> is wrong. Can we see all the code. You can't add a javascript variable directly into your HTML in that way. You would need to assign the ID directly from javascript, by creating the div, settings its id, and appending it to the parent.

Comment: The problem is not the x and y, the problem is how you are setting the id. It looks like your expecting javascript to insert it for you?

Comment: <div class="col-md-6" id="'+x._links.self+'"> That will not work. the has set the id to '+x._links.self+' not to the value of x._links.self

Comment: Okay, what if I create a variable with that value and the assign the ID to that variable?

Comment: I have added an answer that explains let me know if this is clear or give me more detail

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting javascript to magical eval your id into the html.

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="'+x._links.self+'">
```

In order for you to programmatically add in elements with ID's from your JSON you need to add the DIV elements into the DOM from javascript code.

```
$( "#parentdiv" ).append( "<div id='" + x._links.self +  "'></div>" );
```

Then to access that div later you need

```
$("#" + x._links.self); // Or whatever reference to the id you have.
```

Comment: <code>        $('#results').append('<div class="row streamers"><div class="col-md-6 lines"><img src="'+x.logo+'" class="img-fluid small"><h6 class="float-right">'+x.display_name +'</h6></div><div class="col-md-6" id="'+x._links.self+'"><p>'+val+'</p></div></div>');</code>

Comment: and       <pre> if (y.stream===null) {
       
      $("#"+y._links.channel).html('<p>Offline</p>');</pre>

Comment: but not doing it

Comment: Run your code, open up console in say google or whatever browser you use, use element view - look through the html see if the div and its id are what they should be in terms of the value in links.self. Then in console log do document.getElementById(..id) and see if it returns, that will help find out what part of your code is failing - please report back.

Comment: running document.getElementByIdi n the console, it returns the contents of the div, so it is being assigned correctly, so problem must be when I'm accessing it

Comment: Yep so next you need to console.log(y._links.channel) in your above code when you set it to offline run page, check in console log that correct id is written out, i suspect it won't be.

Comment: if (y.stream===null) {console.log("id="+y._links.channel); $("#"+y._links.channel).html('<p>Offline</p>');

Comment: console.log("id="+y._links.channel); returns what I'd expect,however, $('#'+y._links.channel).html(<p>Offline</p>); does not change anything, so I know that my condition is being interpreted correctly, and   I know that my call returns the right string for the ID call, so it must be that I'm not passing it correctly

Comment: Made it work using getElementById().innerHTML thanks for all the help bro!